# Simple jquery slideToggle doesn't work in any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have a simple jquery code for a slide down panel on my website. I have included the jquery.js file in the header. But it still doesn't work. 
Has it something to do with the version?

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Slide Panel</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="panel">
            <br />
            <br />
            <p>Panel</p>
        </div>

        <p class="slide">
            <div class="pull-me">
                Slide Up/Down
            </div>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
.pull-me{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFD700;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.panel {
    background: #ffffbd;
    background-size:90% 90%;
    height:300px;
    display:none;
    font-family:garamond,times-new-roman,serif;
}
.panel p{
    text-align:center;
}
.slide {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-top:solid 2px #cc0000;
}
.pull-me {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    right:-25px;
    width:150px;
    height:20px;
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background:#cc0000;
    text-decoration:none;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
.pull-me p {
    text-align:center;
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pull-me').click(function(){
        $('.panel').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5uMq// Check your console for errors elsewhere in your code.

Comment: yeah I thought it would work, but when I open it in Chrome the panel just doesn't slide down:(

Comment: It's ok with Chrome for me ...

Comment: I have just put it in the fiddle and it doesn't work there either.

Comment: Chrome v.31 works fine in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/v9E5s/). Tip: You should call jQuery library first then your custom scripts!

Comment: Oh now it works in the fiddle, but still not in Chrome when I just open as a HTML file. Do I have to include another version of jQuery?

Comment: Ok I'll post in answer what you should change.

Comment: It also depends on the version of JQuery... for different versions it operates differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Slide Panel</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> <!-- Always first call the jQuery library -->
    <script src="script.js"></script> <!-- Then call your custom scripts -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  <!-- Link tag is selfclosing don't put </link> at the end -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="panel">
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>Panel</p>
    </div>

    <p class="slide">
        <div class="pull-me">
            Slide Up/Down
        </div>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome, just remember to always call first jQuery, jQuery UI and then your custom scripts and if you're including custom scripts directly in your HTML always place them just before `</body>` tag of course between `<script> </script>` tags and with document ready function for each script which is in jQuery shortly `$(function(){ // Your script here });`